# Mysql to Informix query

Tags: mysql, informix

I used following query to retrieve information from a mysql table.

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(fecha,2) ,CONCAT('Semana ', WEEK(fecha)) as y,count(*) as a 
FROM mobile09 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN TODAY - 30 AND TODAY GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

How can I get the same result in a Informix database with same tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to implement your own week of year function for Informix.

Lucky for you, this has already been done at: [IBM Developerworks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510roy/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION day_one_week_one(yyyy INTEGER)
  RETURNING DATE
  WITH(NOT VARIANT)
  DEFINE jan1 DATE;
  LET jan1 = MDY(1, 1, yyyy);
  RETURN jan1 + MOD(11 - WEEKDAY(jan1), 7) - 3;
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION iso8601_weeknum(dateval DATE DEFAULT TODAY)
RETURNING CHAR(2)
WITH(NOT VARIANT)
    DEFINE rv CHAR(8);
    DEFINE yyyy CHAR(4);
    DEFINE ww CHAR(2);
    DEFINE d1w1 DATE;
    DEFINE tv DATE;
    DEFINE wn INTEGER;
    DEFINE yn INTEGER;
    -- Calculate year and week number.
    LET yn = YEAR(dateval);
    LET d1w1 = day_one_week_one(yn);
    IF dateval < d1w1 THEN
        -- Date is in early January and is in last week of prior year
        LET yn = yn - 1;
        LET d1w1 = day_one_week_one(yn);
    ELSE
        LET tv = day_one_week_one(yn + 1);
        IF dateval >= tv THEN
            -- Date is in late December and is in the first week of next year
            LET yn = yn + 1;
            LET d1w1 = tv;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    LET wn = TRUNC((dateval - d1w1) / 7) + 1;
    -- Calculation complete: yn is year number and wn is week number.
    -- Format result.
    LET yyyy = yn;
    IF wn < 10 THEN
        LET ww = "0" || wn;
    ELSE
        LET ww = wn;
    END IF

    RETURN ww;
END FUNCTION;
```

Now you should be able to do

```
select
   year(fecha) || iso8601_weeknum(fecha),
   'Semana ' || iso8601_weeknum(fecha) as y,
   count(*) as a
from
   mobile09
where
   fecha between today - 30 and today
group by
   1, 2
order by
   1 asc;
```